# DLC redeemed on child account, but not showing up in either

Tags: psn, fortnite-battle-royale

I got the redeem code with my PS4 when I signed in with my account 'A', but I could not access the Store because I was under age. So I created a parent account to give me access to the store. By mistake I went to the Store of parent account and redeemed the Neo Versa code. I have not installed Fortnite on the Playstation yet. After installation I logged in to the child account of the Fortnite and found that the skin was not there, so I realized that I had mistakenly redeemed it on the parent account. I logged in to the parent account, but didn't find it there, too. It shows in the transaction I have.

Is it because I redeemed it before installing Fortnite?

How do I transfer the item to the child account?

Answer (score 2):

You describe two separate problems:

- **The DLC not showing up**:

  First, make sure the Neo Versa DLC **has actually been installed**, and not just downloaded:

  > "*From the PS4 home screen, highlight the game that the content belongs to and then press down on the controller. This will bring you to the game page. On the left, select Playstation Store. The window on the right will show you your Add-ons. Select your Add-ons and press X to see a complete list. Check if the content you are looking for appears here and is marked as installed.*"

  If it does not show up there, there might be a problem. It could be resolved after having installed the main game, or trying a re-installation.
  You can also try **restoring your licenses**:

  > "*From the main PS4 menu, go to Settings -> Network Account Management (something like that) -> Restore Licenses*"

  If those steps don't work, I suggest bringing it up with [Sony support](https://www.sony.com/electronics/support).
- **The DLC activated on the wrong account**:

  This is a matter for Sony support. We don't have the tools nor authority to address this. I don't think installation matters that much, but playtime might, so make sure you bring this up with support before playing.

  That being said, they do mention in [one of their FAQs](https://support.playstation.com/s/article/Problems-With-Codes-and-PlayStation-Network-Cards) that activating a game on one account cannot be reversed, however:

  > *The PlayStation™ code was redeemed on the wrong account*
  >
  > ***It is not possible to transfer funds or content between accounts.*** Please verify you are signed into the correct account for PlayStation™ Network before redeeming a code.

  Bear in mind that activating DLC on the parent (primary) account allows it to be used on child accounts:

  > "*Anyone who uses your Primary PS4™ system can enjoy applications you purchase from PlayStation® Store.*"